# How do I get rid of certain strings and numbers in multiple rows using gsub?

Tags: r, leaflet, gsub

I am trying to get rid of certain strings and numbers within multiple rows in my data frame using gsub().

```
New Haven, CT (41.308252, -72924161)
MERIDEN, CT (41.537589, -72.8011)
```

And so on.

But I only want to get the `latitude (41.308252, 41.537589, etc.)` and `longitude (-72924161, -72.8011, etc.)` then put them in separate data frames.

The result should look like:

For latitude

```
1. 41.308252
2. 41.537589
```

For longitude

```
1. -72924161
2. -72.8011
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `sub` here, for a base R option:

```
df$lat <- sub(".*\\((-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*", "\\1", col)
df$lng <- sub(".*\\([^,]+,\\s*(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*", "\\1", col)
```

Here is a sample script to show that the logic works:

```
col <- "New Haven, CT (41.308252, -72924161)"
sub(".*\\((-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*", "\\1", col)
sub(".*\\([^,]+,\\s*(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*", "\\1", col)
```

This outputs:

```
[1] "41.308252"
[1] "-72924161"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I appreciate it.